# Override global context for a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a library which makes use of `node-fetch`, which is available in the global context as `fetch()` or `global.fetch()`

I have another function which does some extra optimizations and caching, which also makes use of `node-fetch` in the global context.

I would like to override the library's call to the global `fetch()` function, and instead to make it call my own `fetch` function.

I can't do: `global.fetch = myFetchFn` because `myFetchFn` also references the global `fetch` so it results in an infinite loop, as it just calls itself.

Is there a way I can "mock" the global `fetch` function to point to my own, but only for that one function.

Something like:

```js
const myFetchFunction = require('custom-fetch-library') // uses global.fetch

const thirdPartyLibraryFn = require('some-third-party-lib') // uses global.fetch

// imaginary override function:
overrideGlobalContext({
  global: {...global, fetch: myFetchFunction},
  function: thirdPartyLibraryFn,
  args: ['foo', 'bar'],
});
```

I looked at things like: `bind()`, `call()` and `apply()`, but they only seem to override `this`, not global context. Is there a way to override the global context?

Comment: You can simply store a reference to the original function in a new variable: `var originalFetch = global.fetch; global.fetch = function() { .... originalFetch(...); ... }`.

Comment: @FelixKling I can't do this, because I don't have control of the custom fetch Function. Its also a third party function which makes use of the global context. If I change the global context, it will no longer work. I need to change the global context for just a single function call. Every other function should still see the original global context.

Comment: And this, dear readers, is why we don't use global variables.

Comment: @Bergi I just cannot handle myself saying... LOL! :D

Comment: @BenjaminTamasi you could try swapping the global function **before** calling what you want, then returning it to the original value. But that's like picking which of your legs to shoot yourself in...

Comment: `node-fetch` is a drop-in replacement for `fetch()` which is avaiable globally on browsers, but not in nodejs. It lets the exact same code work on browsers and nodejs without having to change the code. This is a valid use case for global variables, so just saying "don't use global variables" is not much help to me. Especially since its not my library, I can't make any changes.